# Is there a way to render freestyle edges in 3DS Max?

Tags: 3d, 3ds-max

I'm trying to make a render where the straight wire-frame is rendered together with the curved - 
[image]

Is there a way to render freestyle lines in 3DS Max and combine them with a wire-frame material so that I get a result like that?

Comment: What do you mean with curved? Do you want to render both the wireframe and the freestyle together?

Comment: The curved one is the original geometry smoothed out by the "Turbo-smooth" modifier (shown with thicker lines on the image above). The straight one is the new geometry that is created by the modifier. I called it curved because it follows the contours of the smaller edges.

Comment: Is this the only shape you need to render? Are you going to render a still?

Comment: I'm going for an animation. Would there be a difference in the freestyle otherwise?

Comment: The freestyle would only render the edges, not the grid. Also, do you have to change subdivision levels in the shape?

Comment: What renderer are you using?

Comment: It doesn't matter. I'm trying to make a render that is more concentrated on topology. (Not sure, but I think "Mental ray" is capable for that result). Basically, I want to render the original geometry with the new heometry of the "turbo-smooth" modifier and the level will stay the same.

Comment: Information Updated (with screenshot). If you think that my answer was useful to you and solved your problem please upvote and accept my answer :), Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This can be done using the standard built-in 3ds Max shader *Composite*.

First, open the Material Editor and create a Composite material and **apply** the material to the primitive.

[image]

Now that you have the Composite Material created and applied to the geometry, the next step is to define the **Base Material** and the **Wire Material**.

The slot Base Material has already a **Standard material** and its color will define the main filling color of the wireframe rendering (the surface in other words), that in this case is going to be white. So double-click the Base material and change the diffuse color to white.

After this, add another Standard material to the slot no.1 {as shown in picture 2 (make sure it is checked)}, change the diffuse color to your preferred edge color (black in this case) and **check** the Wire checkbox of the Wire material as in the picture no.3.

[image]

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Note:

- If you want to change the edges thickness, go to the Size parameter which is in the Wire zone in the Extended Parameters rollout of the Standard material parameters of the Wire material.
- It is not possible to render two states of the same geomtery at the same time, you will have to rerender the geometry (with Turbosmooth and without TurboSmooth) and merge the result in one image.

Comment: Thank you. I'm a little surprised that two states are not possible to render, but this is good enough for me.